# ADMOB interstitial ads not working in real-unit-id EVENthough it works on test-unit-id

Tags: android

it has been a week to try to solve this problem...

I keep trying to put interstitial ad to my application.

And when testing with test-unit-id works fine on my application.

BUT! When changing to my real-unit-id, Ad don't be loaded in my application at all..

i don't know why this is happening.

so confused.

I used the same sample code in this tutorial, below link.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

and i uploaded the screenshots in my admob -id.

and i will give my codes in my apps. please let me know what is the problem. thanks in advance :)

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

below is my application codes.

```
1.mainactivity.java


    package admobtest.com.theaterwin.theateradmobtest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long GAME_LENGTH_MILLISECONDS = 3000;

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private Button retryButton;
    private boolean gameIsInProgress;
    private long timerMilliseconds;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-4942856506050335~1501960845");

        // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                startGame();
            }
        });

        // Create the "retry" button, which tries to show an interstitial between game plays.
        retryButton = findViewById(R.id.retry_button);
        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        retryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showInterstitial();
            }
        });

        startGame();
    }

    private void createTimer(final long milliseconds) {
        // Create the game timer, which counts down to the end of the level
        // and shows the "retry" button.
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }

        final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 50) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
                timerMilliseconds = millisUnitFinished;
                textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + ((millisUnitFinished / 1000) + 1));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                gameIsInProgress = false;
                textView.setText("done!");
                retryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // Start or resume the game.
        super.onResume();

        if (gameIsInProgress) {
            resumeGame(timerMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Cancel the timer if the game is paused.
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
        if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ad did not load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startGame();
        }
    }

    private void startGame() {
        // Request a new ad if one isn't already loaded, hide the button, and kick off the timer.
        if (!interstitialAd.isLoading() && !interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resumeGame(GAME_LENGTH_MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private void resumeGame(long milliseconds) {
        // Create a new timer for the correct length and start it.
        gameIsInProgress = true;
        timerMilliseconds = milliseconds;
        createTimer(milliseconds);
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

}


2. Androidmanifest.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="admobtest.com.theaterwin.theateradmobtest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4942856506050335~1501960845"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    </application>

</manifest>


3. vales - strings.xml

    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">TheaterAdmobTest</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="impossible_game">Impossible Game</string>
    <!--Replace with your own ad unit id. -->
    <!--<string name="ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712</string>-->
    <!--this is actual abunit_id 입니다 . -->.
    <string name="ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-4942856506050335/8049265316</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not uploaded your app to google store, the real ads will not show. I've met this case.